# how to parse data on recyclerview using retrofit 2 with given json

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Hello im new with retrofit and json. i have a given json and want to display data in recyclerview. I tried to parse data in getWorkQueue() but something goes wrong.

myJson

```
[
    {
        ""REQUEST_NO"": ""CR-201718-6"",
        ""PROCESS_NAME"": ""CONVEYANCE REIMBURSEMENT"",
        ""STEPNAME"": null,
        ""PROCESSID"": 1,
        ""INSTANCEID"": 6,
        ""AMOUNT"": 250,
        ""RAISED_BY"": ""flologic1"",
        ""RAISED_DATE"": ""12-Sep-2017"",
        ""APPROVED_BY"": ""Flologic2"",
        ""APPROVED_DATE"": null,
        ""BRANCH"": ""101""
    }
]
```

WorkQueueAdapter.java

public class WorkQueueAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<TravelWorkQueue> mDataset;
private Context context;

public WorkQueueAdapter(List<TravelWorkQueue> myDataset, Context mContext) {
    this.mDataset = myDataset;
    this.context = mContext;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    TravelWorkQueue queue = mDataset.get(position);
    viewHolder.raisedBy.setText(queue.getRaisedBy());
    viewHolder.requestNo.setText(queue.getRequestNo());
    viewHolder.trdate.setText(queue.getRaisedDate());
    viewHolder.processName.setText(queue.getProcessName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView raisedBy, requestNo, trdate, processName;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        raisedBy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.raisedBy);
        requestNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.requestNo);
        trdate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.trDate);
        processName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.processName);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearIteam);
    }

}

@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.work_queue_list, parent, false);
    return new DataObjectHolder(view);
}
```

}

And fragment class

public class WorkQueue extends Fragment {

```
public static final String TAG = WorkQueue.class.getSimpleName();
private View rootView;
private ListView myRequestList;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private WorkQueueAdapter mAdapter;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
String userName = "flologic2";

private TravelWorkQueue travelWorkQueue;
List<TravelWorkQueue> travelWorkQueues;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.work_queue, container, false);

    //  userName = getParent().getUserName();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    travelWorkQueues = new ArrayList<>();
    // TravelRequestService  travelRequestService = HDFCService.getTravelRequestService();

    getWorkQueue();

    return rootView;
}

private HomeActivity getParent() {
    return (HomeActivity) getActivity();
}

private void getWorkQueue() {

    Call<List<TravelWorkQueue>> call = HDFCService.getTravelRequestService().getRequestQueqeDetails(userName);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TravelWorkQueue>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TravelWorkQueue>> call, Response<List<TravelWorkQueue>> response) {

            List<TravelWorkQueue> list = response.body();
            TravelWorkQueue workQueue = null;

            //int i=0;
           for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                workQueue = new TravelWorkQueue();
                String requestNo = list.get(i).getRequestNo();
                String raisedBy = list.get(i).getApproverBy();
                String raisedDate = list.get(i).getRaisedDate();
                String processName = list.get(i).getProcessName();

                workQueue.setRequestNo(requestNo);
                workQueue.setRaisedBy(raisedBy);
                workQueue.setRaisedDate(raisedDate);
                workQueue.setProcessName(processName);

                list.add(workQueue);
            i++;


                mAdapter = new WorkQueueAdapter(travelWorkQueues, getActivity());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TravelWorkQueue>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });}}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `something goes wrong`

Comment: Please describe exact problem. also, post `TravelWorkQueue` class. is it not parsing correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues :

- no need of `i++` inside loop
- Create and set adapter outside loop
- **travelWorkQueues has no data , you are adding data to `list` instead add data to `travelWorkQueues`** list or use `list` reference while creating adapter

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    // code
    //i++;

//    mAdapter = new WorkQueueAdapter(travelWorkQueues, getActivity());
//    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      travelWorkQueues.add(workQueue);
}
    mAdapter = new WorkQueueAdapter(travelWorkQueues, getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: yes i did it but it shows only .xml layouts not a parsed data. thanks for reply

Comment: @PradnyaBhagat check the size of `list` and `travelWorkQueues` to confirm that you have the data ,if yes then it means there is something wrong with adapter if no mean you not receiving the data , use logs and toast and some debugging

Comment: Yes there was a issue with travelWorkQueues. Thanks for ur time@Pavneet_Singh

Comment: i am glad that i could help. happy coding

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove i++ from the for loop as it already incrementing inside for loop statment

2.Add the data to "travelWorkQueues" and remove the local list "list" as it is redundant or remove the list "travelWorkQueues" and add pass "list" as 
@Pavneet_Singh mentioned.

3.Move mAdapter creation outside for loop because now you are creating new instance of the adapter everytime.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            workQueue = new TravelWorkQueue();
            String requestNo = list.get(i).getRequestNo();
            String raisedBy = list.get(i).getApproverBy();
            String raisedDate = list.get(i).getRaisedDate();
            String processName = list.get(i).getProcessName();

            workQueue.setRequestNo(requestNo);
            workQueue.setRaisedBy(raisedBy);
            workQueue.setRaisedDate(raisedDate);
            workQueue.setProcessName(processName);

            travelWorkQueues.add(workQueue);

               //Remove this  i++
           }
          //Call this after the for loop
          mAdapter = new WorkQueueAdapter(travelWorkQueues, getActivity()); 
          mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this method. then call `mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()`

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<TravelWorkQueue>> call, Response<List<TravelWorkQueue>> response) {
    List<TravelWorkQueue> list = response.body();
    TravelWorkQueue workQueue = null;
    //int i=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        workQueue = new TravelWorkQueue();
        String requestNo = list.get(i).getRequestNo();
        String raisedBy = list.get(i).getApproverBy();
        String raisedDate = list.get(i).getRaisedDate();
        String processName = list.get(i).getProcessName();

        workQueue.setRequestNo(requestNo);
        workQueue.setRaisedBy(raisedBy);
        workQueue.setRaisedDate(raisedDate);
        workQueue.setProcessName(processName);
        list.add(workQueue);
    } mAdapter = new WorkQueueAdapter(travelWorkQueues, getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```